# Sql Query which filters according to one or more fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

sql Query:

```
Select * 
from   tabEmployee
where  city='Delhi' OR locality='' OR pincode='' OR salary Between '' AND '' OR designation=''
```

I am quite new for sql server.

I want to write a sql query where city is mandatory and other fields may or may not be provided by the user.

I mean to say if one user enters locality='Kirti Nagar'.

Filter should work according to city='Delhi' and locality='Kirti Nagar'.

In other case, any user may enter only salary range.

Then Filter should work according to city='Delhi' and salary Between 5000 AND 10000.

If user doesn't enter any field then filter should work according to city='Delhi' only.

**How can i do this ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select * 
    from   tabEmployee
    where  city='Delhi' AND ISNULL(locality_parameter,locality)=locality AND
    (pincode=pincode_parameter OR pincode_parameter=0) AND
    ISNULL(designation_parameter ,designation)=designation AND
    salary BETWEEN ISNULL(lower,salary) AND ISNULL(upper,salary)
```

Set pincode_parameter=0 when user doesn't enter pincode

Comment: Hi Dony, Thanks for u response.    

    pincode_parameter=110034
    SELECT * FROM dbo.tabEmployee
    WHERE city = 'Delhi' AND pincode = ISNULL(pincode_parameter,pincode)

Result- Returns two rows which have cities = 'Delhi' and pincode = 110034. (OK)

But As i do :

    pincode_parameter=NULL
    SELECT * FROM dbo.dbo.tabEmployee
    WHERE city = 'Delhi' AND pincode = ISNULL(pincode_parameter,pincode)


Result- Returns three rows which have cities = 'Delhi' and pincode = 110034.But it's leaving
those rows which have pincode = NULL .Whereas it should return all pincode(including NULL).

Comment: @user2791156

Now added a new condition :
OR pincode IS NULL

Comment: Hi Dony, 

pincode_parameter=110034 
SELECT * FROM dbo.tabEmployee WHERE city = 'Delhi' AND (pincode = (ISNULL(pincode_parameter,pincode)) OR pincode IS NULL) 

Result- Returns nine rows which have cities = 'Delhi' and pincode = 110034. But now it's taking pincode = NULL rows also.
which was not expected.

But As i do : 
pincode_parameter=NULL 
SELECT * FROM dbo.dbo.tabEmployee WHERE city = 'Delhi' AND (pincode = (ISNULL(pincode_parameter,pincode)) OR pincode IS NULL)

Result- Returns ten rows which have cities = 'Delhi' and pincode = 110034 with pincode = NULL. Works perfectly.Good.

Comment: Bro, i think your query is more close to expected result. Plz help me.

Comment: Bro .. please try this new one @user2791156

Comment: Big Bro, You r Brilliant and very cooperative with others.    Thanks for giving your time for my problem.                          Very-very thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Select * from   tabEmployee
where  city='Delhi' and (locality='Kirti Nagar' OR pincode='411521' OR 
(salary Between '5000' AND    '10000') OR designation='Engineer')
```

Comment: Thanks for u response. My requirement is, don't enter locality/pincode/salary/designation then it should filter according to city='Delhi' Otherwise should filter with city and other field. WHEREAS you enter all fields.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you.
Please check is this solution is work for your single condition.

```
 Select 
     * 
 from   
      tabEmployee
 where  
      city='Delhi' 
      and           
      (locality = CASE WHEN locality_parameter <> '' THEN locality_parameter  ELSE '' END)
      and
      (pincode= CASE WHEN pincode_parameter <> '' THEN pincode_parameter ELSE '' END)
      and 
      (designation= CASE WHEN designation_parameter <> '' THEN designation_parameter ELSE ''          END)
```

Comment: Hi Hardik, Thanks for your response. But your query throws error
"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected".
But if i remove 'OR NULL' , it works. But one field from locality/pincode/salary/designation is mandatory.
My requirement is, don't enter locality/pincode/salary/designation then it should filter according to city='Delhi' Otherwise should filter with city and other field.

Comment: @user2791156 I have edited the answer please check that is this solution is working for single condition

Comment: Doesn't work. It works only when second condition(locality) is true. if it is NULL, it doesn't filter according to city.

Comment: @user2791156 Pleasae check the edit Hope it should work

Comment: Hardik, Thanks FOR u efforts. Still it doesn't work.
I noticed with AND operator all conditions must be true, it won't work if anyone have NULL / ''.

Comment: @user2791156 Can you give me table structure & insert query I will surely give you soution

Comment: Do one thing give me your email id I will email you on it.